# CO2 dynamics-vector correlations

Tags: physical-chemistry, molecular-orbital-theory, uv-vis-spectroscopy

I would like to ask if anyone has any information (schematic diagram)of vector correlations for CO2 molecule. (Is it bending in the excited state with μ in plane? How CO fragment can be ejected after the break?)

Thank you in advance

Comment: What's μ? Also, there is more than one excited state, and more than one _mode of oscillations_.

Comment: μ is dipole moment. I am studying photodissociation of CO2 so I was wondering what is happening if I give a specific amount of energy and break the bond.

Comment: You will need a potential energy surface for the (excited?) state you intend to dissociate from. I would imagine that some of these have been calculated although I can't give you a reference.